# T-SQL - Get last as-at date SUM(Quantity) was not negative

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find a way to get the last date by location and product a sum was positive. The only way i can think to do it is with a cursor, and if that's the case I may as well just do it in code. Before i go down that route, i was hoping someone may have a better idea?

Table:
Product, Date, Location, Quantity

The scenario is; I find the quantity  by location and product at a particular date, if it is negative i need to get the sum and date  when the group was last positive.

```
select 
    Product, 
    Location, 
    SUM(Quantity) Qty,
    SUM(Value) Value
from 
    ProductTransactions PT  
where
    Date <= @AsAtDate
group by 
    Product, 
    Location
```

Comment: You are also grouping by product and location.  Do you want the last positive date for each group, or for the entire table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For the group, I have updated the question to reflect this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> i am looking for the last date where the sum of the transactions previous to and including it are positive

Based on your revised question and your comment, here another solution I hope answers your question.

```
select Product, Location, max(Date) as Date
from (
    select a.Product, a.Location, a.Date from ProductTransactions as a
    join ProductTransactions as b
    on a.Product = b.Product and a.Location = b.Location
    where b.Date <= a.Date
    group by a.Product, a.Location, a.Date
    having sum(b.Value) >= 0
) as T
group by Product, Location
```

The subquery (table T) produces a list of {product, location, date} rows for which the sum of the values prior (and inclusive) is positive.  From that set, we select the last date for each {product, location} pair.

Comment: Sorry, I should not have had the date in my group by, I am wanting the sum to be "as-at", not just transactions for the date.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a set based way using windowed aggregates in order to construct the running total. Depending on the number of rows in the table this could be a bit slow but you can't really limit the time range going backwards as the last positive date is an unknown quantity.

I've used a CTE for convenience to construct the aggregated data set but converting that to a temp table should be faster. (CTEs get executed each time they are called whereas a temp table will only execute once.)

The basic theory is to construct the running totals for all of the previous days using the `OVER` clause to partition and order the `SUM` aggregates. This data set is then used and filtered to the expected date. When a row in that table has a quantity less than zero it is joined back to the aggregate data set for all previous days for that product and location where the quantity was greater than zero.

Since this may return multiple positive date rows the `ROW_NUMBER()` function is used to order the rows based on the date of the positive quantity day. This is done in descending order so that row number 1 is the most recent positive day.  It isn't possible to use a simple `MIN()` here because the `MIN([Date])` may not correspond to the `MIN(Quantity)`.

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT [Date],
        Product,
        [Location],
        SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY Product, [Location] ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS Quantity,
        SUM([Value]) OVER(PARTITION BY Product, [Location] ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS [Value]
    FROM ProductTransactions
    WHERE [Date] <= @AsAtDate
)
SELECT [Date], Product, [Location], Quantity, [Value], Positive_date, Positive_date_quantity
FROM (
    SELECT x1.[Date], x1.Product, x1.[Location], x1.Quantity, x1.[Value],
        x2.[Date] AS Positive_date, x2.[Quantity] AS Positive_date_quantity,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x1.Product, x1.[Location] ORDER BY x2.[Date] DESC) AS Positive_date_row
    FROM x AS x1
    LEFT JOIN x AS x2 ON x1.Product=x2.Product AND x1.[Location]=x2.[Location]
        AND x2.[Date]<x1.[Date] AND x1.Quantity<0 AND x2.Quantity>0
    WHERE x1.[Date] = @AsAtDate
) AS y
WHERE Positive_date_row=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to get the last date of positive quantity come to positive in group?

For example, If you are using SQL Server 2012+:
In following scenario, when the date going to 01/03/2017 the summary of quantity come to 1(-10+5+6).
Is it possible the quantity of following date come to negative again?

```
;WITH tb(Product, Location,[Date],Quantity) AS(
     SELECT 'A','B',CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/01/2017'),-10 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 'A','B','01/02/2017',5 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 'A','B','01/03/2017',6 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 'A','B','01/04/2017',2
)
SELECT  t.Product,t.Location,SUM(t.Quantity) AS Qty,MIN(CASE WHEN t.CurrentSum>0 THEN t.Date ELSE NULL END ) AS LastPositiveDate
FROM (
    SELECT *,SUM(tb.Quantity)OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) AS CurrentSum FROM tb
) AS t GROUP BY t.Product,t.Location
```

```
Product Location Qty         LastPositiveDate
------- -------- ----------- -----------------------
A       B        3           2017-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Hi, no i am looking for the last date where the sum of the transactions previous to and including it are positive.  Thanks.

Comment: @TheRealTy Do you want to get the last date when the sum of quantity become to positive. BTW, what version of SQL Server that you are using

Comment: You can just replace the MIN with MAX in the statement, this will return the latest date when the sum of transaction up to and before that date is positive.